# Excel Subtracting time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Currently trying to setup a formula that will calculate the hours/minutes between two different hours of time.

I currently use the following formula in Cell D3 and receive 12:35am as the answer:

```
=C3-B3
```

[image]

What I would want it to display is 35 minutes, which is the correct amount of time in between (6:42AM and 7:17AM).

Comment: What is the format of the begin and end cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
=TEXT(C3-B3,"[m]")
```

or if you want "minutes" written after

```
=TEXT(C3-B3,"[m] ""minutes""")
```

---

Examples:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

C3-B3 and formatted as [m] will work - either `=TEXT(C3-B3,"[m]")` or just giving the cell a custom number format of `[m]`.

If Begin is 11:45PM and End is 12:15AM you'll only see `#############` as both times are considered to be in the same day, while 12:15AM is the start of the next day.

Try `=IF(C4<B4,(1+C4)-B4,C4-B4)`
If C4 is less than B4 it adds 1 day to the value of End.

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply your formula by the amount of hours in a day (24) and the amount of minutes in an hour (60) in order to convert.

So your formula should be the following.

=(C3-B3)*24*60